# Add class to input form in login form

Tags: login, wp-login-form

is any way to add custom class name to input field in login from in `wp_login_form` function?

```
<input type="text" name="log" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id_username'] ) . '" class="input" value="' . esc_attr( $args['value_username'] ) . '" size="20" tabindex="10" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is no direct filter available to modify the output of username input field. You can do this by enqueuing a js on login page and then adding a css class to username input field. Please see if below helps:

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'add_login_css' );
function add_login_css(){
    wp_register_script(
        'extra-login-css', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/extra-login-css.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        '',
        TRUE
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'extra-login-css' );
}
```

Make sure the path for **extra-login-css.js** mentioned above is correct or else you can update it as per your directory structure. Add the following code in that js file.

```
( function( $ ) {

   $("#user_login").addClass("my-login-username");

} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: While above is quick way to do it, [here is a very old article](https://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/) which tells about customizing the complete form.